# How to modify/retransform JSON array structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
[{"id":"15","heading":"Post1","content":"Post 1 Content","date":"2016-11-09 08:51:37"},
{"id":"16","heading":"Post2","content":"Post 2 Content","date":"2016-11-09 08:52:09"},
{"id":"17","heading":"Post3","content":"Post 3 Content","date":"2015-06-09 08:52:09"}]
```

I have above JSON array. I am trying to convert it into a JSON Object as

```
2016
    Nov
        Post1
        Post2
2015
   June
        Post3
```

I was able to achieve this in PHP by

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($row['2']));
    $month = date('M', strtotime($row['2']));
    $navarray[$year][$month][] = array($row[0], $row[1], $row[3]);
}
```

But can't figure it out in JS.

Comment: I will be passing the output JSON object in Underscore library. But if i could get the diff array structure it would work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike PHP you must create the objects if they don't exists:

```js
var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

ar = [{"id":"15","heading":"Post1","content":"Post 1 Content","date":"2016-11-09 08:51:37"},
{"id":"16","heading":"Post2","content":"Post 2 Content","date":"2016-11-09 08:52:09"},
{"id":"17","heading":"Post3","content":"Post 3 Content","date":"2015-06-09 08:52:09"}]

obj = {}
ar.forEach(function(v) {
  d = new Date(v.date);
  m = monthNames[d.getMonth()]
  if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(d.getFullYear())) {
    obj[d.getFullYear()] = {}
  }
  if (!obj[d.getFullYear()].hasOwnProperty(m)) {
    obj[d.getFullYear()][m] = []
  }
  obj[d.getFullYear()][m].push(v.heading)
})
console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! i spent more than an hour using regex expressions to parse date and making stacks and all!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can doing loop, and for each item, check existence of current year and month, adding it if not exist yet.

```js
var result = {};
var months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]

var j = [{"id":"15","heading":"Post1","content":"Post 1 Content","date":"2016-11-09 08:51:37"},
{"id":"16","heading":"Post2","content":"Post 2 Content","date":"2016-11-09 08:52:09"},
{"id":"17","heading":"Post3","content":"Post 3 Content","date":"2015-06-09 08:52:09"}];

for(var i = 0; i<j.length; i++) {
    var d = new Date(j[i].date);
    var year = ""+d.getFullYear();
    var month = months[d.getMonth()];

    if(!result.hasOwnProperty(year)) {
        result[year] = {};
    }

    if(!result[year].hasOwnProperty(month)) {
        result[year][month] = [];
    }

    result[year][month].push(j[i].heading);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

following iteration will convert your structure according to PHP sample code in OP

```js
var arr1 = [
  {"id":"15","heading":"Post1","content":"Post 1 Content","date":"2016-11-09 08:51:37"},
  {"id":"16","heading":"Post2","content":"Post 2 Content","date":"2016-11-09 08:52:09"},
  {"id":"17","heading":"Post3","content":"Post 3 Content","date":"2015-06-09 08:52:09"}
];
var struct2 = {};

arr1.forEach(function(row) {
  var date = new Date(row.date); // will extract date parts form Date object
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear();
  var mm = date.getMonth() + 1; // months come zero-indexed (from 0-11)
  if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm; // left pad if needed
  struct2[yyyy] = struct2[yyyy] || {}; // init if needed
  struct2[yyyy][mm] = struct2[yyyy][mm] || []; // init if needed
  delete row.date; // drop date if desired
  struct2[yyyy][mm].push(row); // add new record
});

console.log(struct2);

/* fragment below is an extention to answer
 * 2nd concern about how to iterate over this nested structure */
var panel = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(panel);
for (var year in struct2) {
  for (var month in struct2[year]) {
    var section = '<h2>' + year + '-' + month + '</h2>';
    console.log('section: ' + section);
    panel.innerHTML += section;
    for (var i in struct2[year][month]) {
      var item = struct2[year][month][i];
      var content = '<div id="' + item.id + '">';
      content += '<h3>' + item.heading + '</h3>';
      content += '<p>' + item.content;
      content += '</div>';
      console.log('content: ' + content);
      panel.innerHTML += content;
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: extended to answer your concern about looping through the nested structure

Comment: edited previous two variants to make only one, but if inner keys are not needed can be left out and simplify

Comment: How do i loop into this 2d array?

Comment: see extended answer

Comment: Can you have a look at this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40501145/fastest-optimal-way-to-iterate-through-json-object?noredirect=1#comment68248383_40501145 :)