# Fastest/Optimal way to iterate through JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I am getting data in JSON format from my server API and i am parsing it to fill my `ul` and `li` tags.

Following is my raw data format.

```
[{"id":"15","heading":"Post1","content":"Post 1 Content","date":"2016-11-09 08:51:37"},
{"id":"16","heading":"Post2","content":"Post 2 Content","date":"2016-11-09 08:52:09"},
{"id":"17","heading":"Post3","content":"Post 3 Content","date":"2015-06-09 08:52:09"}]
```

My final objective is to draw a html of this format.

```
<li class="hideme coolclass" id="2015">
   <a class="hideMeNav">[-]</a>
   <h2 class="msg">2015</h2>
   <ul id="list2015">
      <li class="hideme coolclass" id="2015Nov">
         <a class="hideMeNav">[-]</a>
         <h3 class="msg">Nov</h3>
         <ul id="list2015Nov">
            <li class="coolclass anchor openpost" id="15">
               <a href="#archive/15" style="display:block">
                  <div class="archiveiconsimg"><img src="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/pets/2016/03/18/bunny-large_trans++qVzuuqpFlyLIwiB6NTmJwfSVWeZ_vEN7c6bHu2jJnT8.jpg"></div>
                  Post1
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li class="hideme coolclass" id="2016">
   <a class="hideMeNav">[-]</a>
   <h2 class="msg">2016</h2>
   <ul id="list2016">
      <li class="hideme coolclass" id="2016Nov">
         <a class="hideMeNav">[-]</a>
         <h3 class="msg">Nov</h3>
         <ul id="list2016Nov">
            <li class="coolclass anchor openpost" id="16">
               <a href="#archive/16" style="display:block">
                  <div class="archiveiconsimg"><img src="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/pets/2016/03/18/bunny-large_trans++qVzuuqpFlyLIwiB6NTmJwfSVWeZ_vEN7c6bHu2jJnT8.jpg"></div>
                  Post2
               </a>
            </li>
            <li class="coolclass anchor openpost" id="17">
               <a href="#archive/17" style="display:block">
                  <div class="archiveiconsimg"><img src="http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/pets/2016/03/18/bunny-large_trans++qVzuuqpFlyLIwiB6NTmJwfSVWeZ_vEN7c6bHu2jJnT8.jpg"></div>
                  Post3
               </a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Basically its in the format

```
2016
    Nov
        Post1
        Post2
2015
   June
        Post3
```

So, for this i am initially converting my raw data into array.

[How to modify/retransform JSON array structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40499946/how-to-modify-retransform-json-array-structure)

```
{
  "2015": {
    "Jun": [
      "Post3"
    ]
  },
  "2016": {
    "Nov": [
      "Post1",
      "Post2"
    ]
  }
}
```

And then using this **3 NESTED LOOP** for generate HTML. I am getting a strong sensation that this calculation can be reduced. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
for (var id in struct2) {
result += '
<li class="hideme coolclass" id="'+id+'">
   <a class="hideMeNav">[-]</a>
   <h2 class="msg">'+id+'</h2>
   <ul id="list'+id+'">
      ';
      for(var _id in struct2[id]){
      result += "
      <li class='hideme coolclass' id='"+id+_id+"'>
         <a class='hideMeNav'>[-]</a>
         <h3 class='msg'>"+_id+"</h3>
         <ul  id='list"+id+_id+"'>
            ";
            for(var __id in struct2[id][_id]){
            console.log(struct2[id][_id][__id].id);
            console.log(struct2[id][_id][__id].heading);
            console.log(struct2[id][_id][__id].content);
            result += "
            <li class='coolclass anchor openpost' id='"+struct2[id][_id][__id].id+"'>
               <a href='#archive/"+struct2[id][_id][__id].id+"' style='display:block'>
                  <div class='archiveiconsimg'><img src='http://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/pets/2016/03/18/bunny-large_trans++qVzuuqpFlyLIwiB6NTmJwfSVWeZ_vEN7c6bHu2jJnT8.jpg' ></div>
                  "+struct2[id][_id][__id].heading+"
               </a>
            </li>
            "
            }
            result += '
         </ul>
      </li>
      ';
      }
      result += '
   </ul>
</li>
';
}
```

Comment: If you code works and objective of question is Optimisations/Improvements, please post it on [CodeReviews](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is not a code, this is BRUTEFORCE. I am asking for a code. I just printed those nasty lines for quick output.

Comment: I still don't understand the objective of question, but if you  want **fastest** way, `for` is what you must use. Any other methods (array methods) are wrapper over it, to reduce amount of code to be written and and always slower then `for`

Comment: But something's telling me that mapping or anything which will allow me to access values directly is bit faster than `n^3` loop. Like dynamic over iteration.

Comment: What is the last id attribute supposed to contain ? the last 2 digits of the year?

Comment: @GraveyardQueen No! `__id` is just a variable i had to use to access elements. Its really a big mess! :( and `id` contains years like `2016`, `_id` contains months `Nov` and `struct2[id][_id][__id].id` contains object `id`  that contains database value.

Comment: You will have to use 3 for loops since the format of the json array is such that it is an array in an array in an array.if it were possible to predict the size of the array then you could call the array elements like this array[0][0][0] and so on

Comment: @unkn0wn if your concern is about performance impact, mostly from a BigO point of view, notice that these three nested loops won't make `n^3` **if** `n` is said to be the initial input data you posted at the top, which you referred as the "raw data". You can iterate over that data in many ways, but the total amount is `n`, and as long as you don't repeat element while iterating, then you're sticking to `O(n)` no matter if a single loop or three nested loops

Comment: @GraveyardQueen @arhak I see. I was just worried, because this is the method i'd use when using a language with no object orientation support like `C` but when it comes to use heavily object oriented language like `javascript/$` i guess i could give some extra memory in return for less computation. Thanks for your inputs.